# Application maximized dock stuff

Tags: c#, winforms, styles, maximize

Alright, the title sound rubbisch, i know. (and sorry for the bad english)

I'm working on an Windows Form Application in C#.

I've got an form (form1), with an menustrip, an statusstrip and splitcontainer.

I've placed everything in the designer at the way i want it. The form got an size of 990:788. When i run the program, and if I maximize the program, then the split container go over the statusstrip.

How can i hold it at it's place (like 5% from bottom, 10% from top or something like that in pixels...)

I'm new to styling al these object, so any thougts will be usefull...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may dock those items by using the Properties Window... statusstrip Docking="down" menustrip Docking="up" and the split container Docking="fill".

Then the items will automatically resize when the form resizes.

Comment: Alright, thanks. That worked. But do you know the answer to this: http://i.imgur.com/lrBQ7.jpg
It is the menu strip. At the left, the color is gray (and i want that), but at the right, it's white (or is it just me...)... how can i fixe that, that it will be 1 color; (gray)

Comment: Ask 1 question per question, and not in the comments.

Comment: it´s really white at the right end, and you may fix it in one or more propertis of the object, here is the msdn link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.aspx

Comment: @Paedow, Thanks for the help... I will look at the msdn again, mayby i overlooked it before....

Comment: I have the solution: the menuStrip background is maybe not set to a color but rather to an image Check the Property "  BackgroundImage" if its empty or not... (don´t have vs right here)

Comment: @Paedow, that isn't the solution, i didn't had an background image. But the solution is this: the rendermode was set to managerrendermode, and that must be set to system, and it looks normal ;-) but thanks for thinking with me